# In React, why can't you add a key to an empty fragment (short syntax)?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, design-decisions

I know that, in React, you can't add a key to an empty fragment:

```
// will result in an error
< key={'foo'} > 
 {...}
</>
```

Instead, you need to use `React.Fragment`:

```
// works fine
<React.Fragment key="foo">
   {...}
</React.Fragment>
```

The [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax) notes this, but it doesn't explain **why**, and I'm curious. Is it a limitation in JSX? Or is it a design decision that React made for some reason?

Edit: I found [this post](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html#jsx-fragment-syntax). It sounds like `Fragment` came first, then `<>` followed (and was upstreamed to JSX). But why didn't they make it so it could be parameterized? Just curious on the context of the decision and if there's an underlying reason, since I don't understand JSX all that well.

Comment: I guess that's a syntax limitation of jsx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was actually a question that I also had in mind. After asking around from people who made the pull requests for keyed fragments and snooping around the source code I think I have the answer.

I believe that it would be easy to add a key to the shorthand syntax as well since they get reconciled the same way. However if we were to add a key in the shorthand syntax it would be like as such:

```
<key="1">foo</>
```

Now this leads to a lot of confusion, is key another tag? if not, then what if JSX adds another `<key></key>` tag. That will raise even more confusion. Which is why all shorthand syntax do not support attributes.

###### The tradeoff for adding a key attribute is simply too high

Comment: Hmm, seems reasonable, surprised I didn't think of that! Thanks for digging into this. I suppose they could have reserved the <key> tag, but I can understand why they wouldn't do it, and it'd be strange to have a tag like that. I suppose they could have done separate syntax like `<! key..` but that would require parser changes and is kinda ugly. Well, TIL!

Comment: Any links you have to the source code would be of interest to me, btw

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/4700, https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/10783, https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/3030